# A word for when something borrows heavily from a predecessor

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word which I've seen used most often when describing works of music, art or literature. I thought the word was "diminutive" but that appears to be incorrect.

I am *not* looking for a word which describes *something based on a prototype* (which has already been asked [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118923/what-is-the-word-for-something-that-is-based-on-a-prototype)).

Instead, I am looking for the word which describes, somewhat pejoratively, something which *borrows* elements from a predecessor or predecessors that *were not intended to be prototypes*.

Here's an example sentence:

> The new album from the Ga Ga Dolls is nice to listen to, but terribly _______, since it borrows so many themes from the Blackberries album.

Note: the word I'm looking for is not "plagiarism".

Comment: Probably a duplicate: [How to describe a document that is a near plagiarism of another](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170120/how-to-describe-a-document-that-is-a-near-plagiarism-of-another/170194#170194).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not a duplicate. The senses of the two questions are dissimilar and looking for different answers. The question you refers to even notes that “derivative”, which is the correct answer to this question, is not the word they are looking for. So, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

***derivative*** [as an adjective](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/derivative#Adjective) might work in some circumstances

Comment: I think this must be the word the OP is thinking of.

Comment: That's it—I knew it started with a 'd'. Thanks!

Comment: As soon as you said "it's not *diminutive*" I knew you were trying to think of "*derivative*".

Comment: How apt; Newton invented derivatives and said, *If I have seen further it is by standing on the shoulders of giants.*

Comment: This has two orthographical errors. Please use standard written English: you need to start written English sentences with a capital letter and place a full stop (a period) at the end. It also could use more substantive text around it explaining **why** you think this word would work here.

Answer (score 8):

You may be thinking of ***imitative*** which means:

> copying or reproducing the features of an original, *esp in an inferior manner*
>
> - ***imitative*** painting ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/imitative))

[OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=imitative%20meaning&oq=imitative%20mean&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j69i57j0i10i433i512j0i10i512l7.4524j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) defines it as:

> following a model or example *without any attempt at originality*.
>
> - I found the film pretentious and ***imitative***.

Answer (score 8):

> emulative
>
> 1. To strive to equal or excel, especially through imitation: an older pupil whose accomplishments and style I emulated.

[www.thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com)

Answer (score 5):

***Pastiche*** is often used in literature or visual arts.

Comment: This one is also quite apt for my purposes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another is **unoriginal**. [(Merriam-Webster:)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unoriginal)

> Lacking originality; not original.